# How to disable future dates in calendar using Angular 2+ reactive form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular5

I am working on calendar. I want to set maximum date as today and disable future dates.

HTML

```
 <div [ngClass]="setClassDOB()">
 <input type="date" formControlName="dob" name="dob">
 </div>
```

What should I do in component side(TS)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `ts` file define next function:

```
getToday(): string {
   return new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
}
```

And in `html` bind *max* as follow

```
<input type="date" formControlName="dob" name="dob" [max]="getToday()">
```

and if you want to disable past dates and show the calendar from today's date then just change [max] to min [min]...it will work

Comment: Bro, thanks its working.  Can you tell me another thing. If the selected date is 100 yrs from today it should show error. How to do that?

Comment: @Chris to avoid this type of errors just create same function for minimal date and bind it to [min]

Answer (score 0):

maxDate =  formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd','en');

<input type="date" id="DDob"  [max]="maxDate" >

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)